# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLocation' of null" when starting an angular2-meteor project

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

I've been playing with angular2-meteor with typescript lately and I've already created several projects.

the problem that I'm having occurred before, and to resolve it I removed and reinstalled node_modules and meteor to resolve the issue.

since the issue happened again, I'm posting this question instead of reinstalling everything to see if someone can give me some insights about this error.

In general I created a angular2-meteor project as described at http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping

for now the application is very basic.

I have a main app.ts in the client directory with the following code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import {Component,provide} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {MdToolbar} from '@angular2-material/toolbar';

import {Welcome} from './imports/pages/welcome/welcome';
import {Statistics} from './imports/pages/statistics/statistics';


@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   templateUrl: 'client/app.html',
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,MdToolbar],
   providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })]
})
@Routes([
 { path: '/', component: Welcome },
 {path: '/statistics',component:Statistics}  
])
class BingoDriveStatisticsApp {

}

bootstrap(BingoDriveStatisticsApp);
```

as you can see, I have two views components, 'Welcome' and 'Statistics'. I'm also using angular2-material for the toolbar for now.

the view components pretty much contains templateUrl that points to an empty html file.

example: welcome.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 templateUrl: '/imports/pages/welcome/welcome.html'
})
export class Welcome {

}
```

my main index.html file in client directory contains:

```
<body><app></app></body>
```

and app.html contains:

```
<md-toolbar [color]="primary">
    <span>BingoDrive Statistics</span>&nbsp;
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">Welcome</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/statistics']">Statistics</a>
</md-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

again.. i don't think that this error got anything to do with my code, since it has happened before on other projects.

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bingodrive-statistics",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "angular2-meteor": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "^0.5.5",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "=0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "=5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

my `.meteor/packages` file contains the following:

```
meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var            # Reactive variable for tracker
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

angular2-compilers
barbatus:angular2-runtime
accounts-password
```

after all of that... the error message itself! :)

it's repeated and very long but the main exception is this:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
VM2668:27 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLocation' of null
VM2668:27 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
VM2668:27 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLocation' of null
at BrowserPlatformLocation._init (browser_platform_location.js:19)
at new BrowserPlatformLocation (browser_platform_location.js:14)
at DebugAppView.Object.defineProperty.get (BingoDriveStatisticsApp_Host.template.js:35)
at DebugAppView.Object.defineProperty.get (BingoDriveStatisticsApp_Host.template.js:47)
at DebugAppView.Object.defineProperty.get (BingoDriveStatisticsApp_Host.template.js:53)
at DebugAppView.Object.defineProperty.get (BingoDriveStatisticsApp_Host.template.js:59)
at DebugAppView._View_BingoDriveStatisticsApp_Host0.injectorGetInternal (BingoDriveStatisticsApp_Host.template.js:82)
at DebugAppView.AppView.injectorGet (view.js:96)
at DebugAppView.injectorGet (view.js:269)
at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.js:20)
VM2668:27 ERROR CONTEXT:
VM2668:27 
DebugContext {_view: _View_BingoDriveStatisticsApp_Host0, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 0}
```

any ideas what's going on ?

## update

I backup the project to another directory, after that delete node_modules and executed `meteor npm install --save`. after that, the application works fine. so.. something broke the application, and by deleting node_modules and re-creating it i resolved the issue.

so... i hate to do that every time I start a new project.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try changing dev dependencies from 
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1", to "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "^0.5.5",

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue of routing only by changing package.json for reflect-metadata and for rxjs. We should not use latest version of reflect (0.1.3).
"reflect-metadata": "=0.1.2",
"rxjs": "=5.0.0-beta.6",